framextopmargin not working listings.sty
Tried with
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor,listings}

\usepackage{showframe}
\begin{document}

\lstset{%
    frame=leftline,%
    framerule=3pt,%
framextopmargin=20pt,
    rulecolor=\color{black!60},%
        extendedchars=true,%
    columns=fixed,%
    basicstyle=\tt\footnotesize,%
    keywordstyle=\tt\bfseries,%
        showstringspaces=false,%
        showspaces=false,%
        tabsize=2,%
    breaklines,
breakatwhitespace,%
        showtabs=false,%
        captionpos=b,
    backgroundcolor=\color{black!10},%
}

\noindent
\begin{lstlisting}[framextopmargin=120pt,language=python,caption={Example of a textual specification for a traditional software function as common in software projects, describing what the function does and how to compute the results (pointing to another document for details in this case). A developer can implement this function according to the specification, without needing to understand the rest of the system. Another developer working on another part of the system can rely on this function without having access to its implementation.}]
def compute_deductions(agi, expenses):
    """
    Compute deductions based on provided adjusted gross income
    and expenses in customer data.

    See tax code 26 U.S. Code A.1.B, PART VI.

    Adjusted gross income must be a positive value.
    Returns computed deduction value.
    """
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}

In this example, framextopmargin=20pt, not working properly.

What exactly is framextopmargin suppose to mean for frame=leftline? If you change it to frame=lines it is interpreted.

Thanks, if I changed to frame=lines, then it works fine, but my case, I need the rule at left side only and the text offset by 12pt at all sides

Perhaps you should combine this with tcolorbox instead. It is a lot easier to constrol the decorations on listings via the tcolorbox interface. It also fixes the "line bug" in the background color of listings.

@daleif Yes, will try per you suggested

I did with combination of mdframed and listing, thanks for your guidance
